# Winston daily rotation node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I use logging through the `winston / daily rotation` plugin. Now I want a log file every day, this is going well. 
But now I would like to zip the log of the day before.

Does anyone have a good solution to test this without having to wait a day?

This is my logger:

```
const write = new (winston.Logger)(
{       
    transports: [       
        new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
            //filename: `${logDir}/%DATE%-log`, 
            filename: `${logDir}/${Math.random()}`,
            timestamp: tsFormat,
            datePattern: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            prepend: true,
            zippedArchive:true,
            maxFiles: 3
```

As you can see, I tried it with `Math.random()` but that does not work.

I fill my test file this way:

```
const str = 'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!';
setInterval(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        write.info(str);
}, 5);
```